# AJAX DIV refresh solely in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I currently have this drop-down DIV combo shown below, based on the user selection it matches the option ID with the DIV and displays the information.

This has been acheived with jQuery but to make it work with the rest of the scripts on the page it needs to be acheieved with JavaScript, which I'm not sure how to do. AJAX seems the only option to do this and refresh the content of the DIV based on the selection, I'm just not sure how to acheive this in JavaScript only.

Is there a way to acheive this in JavaScript only with or without AJAX? It needs to be done in Vanilla JS for speed reasons and to allow it to be placed with other scripts.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#menu').on( 'change keyup', function() {
        var selected = this.value;
        // Load data
        $('.noselection').hide();
        $('.hideprev').hide();      
        $('.' + selected).show();
});
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="menu">
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January</option>
    <option value="February21">February</option>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January</option>
      <option value="February20">February</option>
      <option value="March20">March</option>
      <option value="April20">April</option>
      <option value="May20">May</option>
      <option value="June20">June</option>
      <option value="July20">July</option>
      <option value="August20">August</option>
      <option value="September20">September</option>
      <option value="October20">October</option>
      <option value="November20">November</option>
      <option value="December20">December</option>
</select>
<div class="content">

  <div class="noselection">You need to make a selection above first</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="January20 hideprev">Content from January 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="February20 hideprev">Content from February 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="March20 hideprev">Content from March 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="April20 hideprev">Content from April 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="May20 hideprev">Content from May 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="June20 hideprev">Content from June 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="July20 hideprev">Content from July 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="August20 hideprev">Content from August 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="September20 hideprev">Content from September 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="October20 hideprev">Content from October 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="November20 hideprev">Content from November 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="December20 hideprev">Content from December 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="January21 hideprev">Content from January 2021</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="February21 hideprev">Content from February 2021</div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be helpful if you clarify what precisely you mean by "make it work with the rest of the scripts on the page".

Comment: By "Vanulla JS" are you referring to some obscure javascript library? Or did you mean "vanilla JS"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add / remove class when selected option is updated. via js, you need to add an event listener, then loop on your content div. Since the contents to show/hide stand already here, switching a class to update display state should be enough..

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

basic possible example

```js
let select = document.querySelector("#menu");
let options = document.querySelectorAll(".content>div");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
// here do something once selected option is changed 

// example looping on a few div and comparing classname to select.value 
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].classList.remove("showprev");
    if (options[i].classList.contains(this.value)) {
      options[i].classList.add("showprev");
    }
// end loop example     
  }
});
```

```css
.hideprev {
  display: none;
}

.showprev {
  display: block;
}

/* from your previous post */

select {
  cursor:pointer; /* show it is clickable  */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select id="menu">
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January</option>
    <option value="February21">February</option>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January</option>
      <option value="February20">February</option>
      <option value="March20">March</option>
      <option value="April20">April</option>
      <option value="May20">May</option>
      <option value="June20">June</option>
      <option value="July20">July</option>
      <option value="August20">August</option>
      <option value="September20">September</option>
      <option value="October20">October</option>
      <option value="November20">November</option>
      <option value="December20">December</option>
</select>
<div class="content">
  <div class="hideprev showprev">You need to make a selection above first</div>
  <div class="January20 hideprev">Content from January 2020</div>
  <div class="February20 hideprev">Content from February 2020</div>
  <div class="March20 hideprev">Content from March 2020</div>
  <div class="April20 hideprev">Content from April 2020</div>
  <div class="May20 hideprev">Content from May 2020</div>
  <div class="June20 hideprev">Content from June 2020</div>
  <div class="July20 hideprev">Content from July 2020</div>
  <div class="August20 hideprev">Content from August 2020</div>
  <div class="September20 hideprev">Content from September 2020</div>
  <div class="October20 hideprev">Content from October 2020</div>
  <div class="November20 hideprev">Content from November 2020</div>
  <div class="December20 hideprev">Content from December 2020</div>
  <div class="January21 hideprev">Content from January 2021</div>
  <div class="February21 hideprev">Content from February 2021</div>

</div>
```

> **p.s.** no need to delete a question and repost it almost right away, it can take a few hours and even days before someone answers. Real human are on the other side with private life and eventually jobs to do too.

Comment: Reposted to give the question more clarity and change the scope slightly so it made more sense, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: How would you go about doing this twice on one page? @G-Cyrillus

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is a JavaScript library which allows you to use full potential of JavaScript.
Among other functions, it includes AJAX to submit forms.
So it is already JavaScript code.

You can also get rid of JQuery functions and put the code with the rest of the Javascript like this :

```
function myFunction() {
        var e = document.getElementById("menu");
        var selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        // Load data
        document.getElementsByClassName("noselection")[0].style.display = "none";
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hideprev"); 
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName(selected)[0].style.display = "block";
};
```

```
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

With a "onchange" function on the HTML

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="menu" onchange="myFunction()">
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January</option>
    <option value="February21">February</option>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January</option>
      <option value="February20">February</option>
      <option value="March20">March</option>
      <option value="April20">April</option>
      <option value="May20">May</option>
      <option value="June20">June</option>
      <option value="July20">July</option>
      <option value="August20">August</option>
      <option value="September20">September</option>
      <option value="October20">October</option>
      <option value="November20">November</option>
      <option value="December20">December</option>
</select>
<div class="content">

  <div class="noselection">You need to make a selection above first</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="January20 hideprev">Content from January 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="February20 hideprev">Content from February 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="March20 hideprev">Content from March 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="April20 hideprev">Content from April 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="May20 hideprev">Content from May 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="June20 hideprev">Content from June 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="July20 hideprev">Content from July 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="August20 hideprev">Content from August 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="September20 hideprev">Content from September 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="October20 hideprev">Content from October 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="November20 hideprev">Content from November 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="December20 hideprev">Content from December 2020</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="January21 hideprev">Content from January 2021</div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="February21 hideprev">Content from February 2021</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I know what AJAX is, the same functionality is desired in Vanilla JS rather than using jQuery to acheive it.